# How to resolve java.util.zip.ZipException error in python

Tags: python, exception

I become an error while running or debugging python program: `Error running 'prog_re_dh.py': java.util.zip.ZipException:invalid distance too far back`  
A few minutes ago everything was working perfectly. I thing, I have not changed anything, or at least knowingly. 
No python script works at the moment. 
Could someone help me to handle the problem ?

Comment: What is the code?

Comment: No script is running. I'm not sure, but I doubt it has anything to do with the codes.